# Help to identify Video Amp IC - 4 channel used for Analogue RGB video buffer

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, video

[image]Way back some 10 yrs ago I used a Chip for RGB video buffer amplifier.it only provided some 3dB gain.  It required no external components , had 4 internal video amplifiers in a 14 pin dil package. I lost all documentation and cannot remember the number or brand. Not sure if it was ANxxxx or uPCxxxx or anything else. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Managed to find it, It was the TEA5116.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/193109)

Comment: @LiorBilia - Maybe I need my coffee, but how does this not answer the question?

Comment: Looks like an answer to this question to me.

Comment: @MCG - Why would someone put an answer in their own question? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it was similar to this Maxim chip (that is also capable of some input routing): -

[image]

Maxim have a few offerings so if this isn't the part maybe you should pop along to their website for further investigation? Maybe this 14 pin video buffer amplifier (note the standard pin-out as per many op-amp devices - does this ring any bells?): -

[image]

There is also the MAX4395 - maybe try [this](https://para.maximintegrated.com/en/search.mvp?fam=vid_amp) list of potential parts.

Comment: Hi Andy, many thanks for your help, however, I now found the pcb layout I used 11 years ago and realise the IC was in fact 18 pin. I need this particular IC for 2 reasons; I have already the pcb layout  and I also must have ample stock of these but without the number I will not be able to search it. I added the pcb layout and from it I can make out pinouts as follows; VDD pin 7, Inputs pins 1,2,8,16 , Outputs pins 4,6,14,15 .